# How do you move items betwen two listboxes on MVC - JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have looked at other SO topics on this and they end up being either really old or using WebForms. I have an MVC view in which I have two listboxes. I want to move items back and forth between the two listboxes. The View is:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
       @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAttributes, Model.Attributes, new {id="listBoxAvail", SIZE = 5} ) 

        <input type="submit" name="add" 
               id="add" value="MoveRight" />

        <input type="submit" name="remove" 
               id="remove" value="MoveLeft" />

        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAttributes2, Model.SelectedItems, new { id = "listBoxSel", SIZE = 5})
    }
```

The ViewModel is:

```
    public class OptInViewModel
        {
            public IEnumerable<string> SelectedAttributes { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<string> SelectedAttributes2 { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Attributes { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }
        }

And the Controller code is:

 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AttributeEntities db = new AttributeEntities();
            List<SelectListItem> listSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<SelectListItem> listSelItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var attributes in db.HarmonyAttributes)
            {
                SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = attributes.AttributeName,
                    Value = attributes.AtrributeLabel,
                    Selected = false
                };
                listSelectListItems.Add(selectList);
            }

            foreach (var sel in db.SelectedHarmonyAttributes)
            {
                SelectListItem selList = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = sel.CustomLabel,
                    Value = sel.HarmonyAttribute_ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = false
                };
                listSelectListItems.Add(selList);
            }

            OptInViewModel viewModel = new OptInViewModel
            {
                Attributes = listSelectListItems,
                SelectedItems = listSelItems
            };


            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

I used JQuery to try to do this but it's not working (nothing gets transferred to 2nd listbox). Anyone kinow what's wrong?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("add").click(function () {
                $("#listBoxAvail > option:selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).remove().appendTo("#listBoxSel");
                });
            });

            $("remove").click(function () {
                $("#listBoxSel > option:selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).remove().appendTo("#listBoxAvail");
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes you need to use javascript unless you do a postback or an ajax update

Comment: Can you show me the JavaScript code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108607/move-and-remove-listbox-item-to-another-listbox-using-jquery-in-same-places

Comment: I got some JQuery from there. modified it, but I can't get it work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jQuery-Dual-Listbox` plugin for jQuery. It requires a bit of setup but then works well enough in the MVC environment. One caveat is that in order for your selected values in the 2nd listbox to be posted back to the server for processing, you need to ensure that all items in that listbox are `selected` before the form gets submitted.

e.g. for your markup:

```
<script src="jQuery.dualListBox-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.configureBoxes({
        box1View: 'listBoxAvail',
        box2View: 'listBoxSel',
        to1: 'remove',
        to2: 'add',
        allTo1: 'remove-all',  //you must create this button
        allTo2: 'add-all',     //you must create this button
        useFilters: false
    });
});
$("#listBoxSel").closest("form").on("submit",
    function() {
        //only selected options in listbox get POSTed back!
        $("#listBoxSel > option").prop("selected", true);
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

[Source](https://github.com/parvez/jQuery-Dual-Listbox)

Comment: I tried this but it gives me an error in the line  $("#SelectedAttributes2 > option").prop("selected", true);

Comment: I've edited the code sample to match your control names (`#listBoxSel`), but even that should not have caused an error. It would simply have done nothing. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Replace buttons type from submit to to button like below

```
<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="MoveRight" />
<input type="button" name="remove" id="remove" value="MoveLeft" />
```

In your JavaScript correct selectors prepend # to ids, it should work!

`$("add")` to `$("#add")`

and

`$("remove")` to `$("#remove")`

If you want you can reduce it to

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(document)
        .on("click", "#add", function() {
          $("#listBoxAvail :selected").remove().appendTo("#listBoxSel");
        })
        .on("click","#remove", function() {
          $("#listBoxSel :selected").remove().appendTo("#listBoxAvail");
        });
    });
  </script>
```