# MVC Two listboxes, Why does selected value moved to 2nd listbox flash and disapear?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, listbox

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471097/whats-wrong-with-this-jquery-code-for-multiple-listboxes#26471136), I found out what I was doing wrong with my jQuery code to transfer items between two MVC listboxes I have. The problem is that, even though the code works, it moves the selected item from the first listbox to the 2nd for a split second and disappears. I don't know if this is a client side problem or a MVC problem?

The markup:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>   
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#add").click(function () {
                $("#listBoxAvail > option:selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).remove().appendTo("#listBoxSel");
                });
            });

            $("#remove").click(function () {
                $("#listBoxSel > option:selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).remove().appendTo("#listBoxAvail");
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
           @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAttributes, Model.Attributes, new {id="listBoxAvail", SIZE = 5} ) 

            <input type="submit" name="add" 
                   id="add" value="MoveRight" />

            <input type="submit" name="remove" 
                   id="remove" value="MoveLeft" />

            <input type="submit" name="remove-all" id="remove-all" value="RemAll" />

            <input type="submit" name="select-all" id="select-all" value="SelAll" />

            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAttributes2, Model.SelectedItems, new { id = "listBoxSel", SIZE = 5})
        } 
    </div>
</body>
```

The MVC view model is:

```
 public class OptInViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> SelectedAttributes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> SelectedAttributes2 { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Attributes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }
    }
```

And the Controller code is:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AttributeEntities db = new AttributeEntities();
            List<SelectListItem> listSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<SelectListItem> listSelItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var attributes in db.HarmonyAttributes)
            {
                SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = attributes.AttributeName,
                    Value = attributes.AtrributeLabel,
                    Selected = false
                };
                listSelectListItems.Add(selectList);
            }

            foreach (var sel in db.SelectedHarmonyAttributes)
            {
                SelectListItem selList = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = sel.CustomLabel,
                    Value = sel.HarmonyAttribute_ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = false
                };
                listSelectListItems.Add(selList);
            }

            OptInViewModel viewModel = new OptInViewModel
            {
                Attributes = listSelectListItems,
                SelectedItems = listSelItems
            };


            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Comment: try a bit of debugging. in your each loop, instead of adding item into new listbox, display it like console.log($(this).val()) and see what is happening. try the same with .text() as well. watch for what are you trying to move ... value or listbox item ?

Comment: I answered your similar question, please have a llok http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467378/how-do-you-move-items-betwen-two-listboxes-on-mvc-jquery-not-working; as @stephen said change button `type` from `submit` to `button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controls for adding and removing are `<input type="submit" ..>` which submits the form. Change them to button elements

```
<button type="button" id="add">MoveRight"</button>
<button type="button" id="remove">MoveLeft"</button>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is a client side issue, rather appending your options to the list box try creating the options since some of the browsers may not support I suspect which is causing the trouble.

```
var op = new Option();
op.value = 1;
op.text = "First entry";
textnode2.options.add(op);
```

Refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275972/creating-dropdown-dynamically-javascript).